# pandas dataframe apply using additional arguments

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, apply

with below example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'signal':[1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0],'product':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B'],'price':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7],'price2':[1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2]})
```

I have a function "fill_price" to create a new column 'Price_B' based on 'signal' and 'price'. For every 'product' subgroup, Price_B equals to Price if 'signal' is 1. Price_B equals previous row's Price_B if signal is 0. If the subgroup starts with a 0 'signal', then 'price_B' will be kept at 0 until 'signal' turns 1.

Currently I have:

```
def fill_price(df, signal,price_A):
p = df[price_A].where(df[signal] == 1)
return p.ffill().fillna(0).astype(df[price_A].dtype)
```

this is then applied using:

```
df['Price_B'] = fill_price(df,'signal','price')
```

However,  I want to use df.groupby('product').apply() to apply this fill_price function to two subsets of 'product' columns separately, and also apply it to both'price' and 'price2' columns. Could someone help with that?

I basically want to do:

```
df.groupby('product',groupby_keys=False).apply(fill_price, 'signal','price2')
```

Comment: Does this work?  `df.groupby('product').apply(lambda x: fill_price(x,'signal','price'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can use this syntax:

```
df['Price_B'] = df.groupby('product').apply(lambda x: fill_price(x,'signal','price2')).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
```

Output:

```
    price  price2 product  signal  Price_B
0       1       1       A       1        1
1       2       2       A       0        1
2       3       1       A       0        1
3       4       2       A       1        2
4       5       1       A       0        2
5       6       2       A       0        2
6       7       1       A       0        2
7       1       2       B       0        0
8       2       1       B       1        1
9       3       2       B       0        1
10      4       1       B       0        1
11      5       2       B       1        2
12      6       1       B       0        2
13      7       2       B       0        2
```

You can write this much simplier without the extra function.

```
df['Price_B'] = (df.groupby('product',as_index=False)
                   .apply(lambda x: x['price2'].where(x.signal==1).ffill().fillna(0))
                   .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
```

Comment: It works. I'm a bit confused though, as 1. why do we reset index at the end 2. the function applies to a dataframe, but in the lambda function we are feeding rows through it?

Thanks

Comment: It is the way your function is built, you are returning a dataframe with an index, then groupby is putting a new index of the group.  Yes, you function takes a dataframe as it first argument, in the lambda function we are just passing a few "grouped" rows of the dataframe to your function and it is returning a dataframe which we then strip the outslide index off and let Pandas align your original dataframe with the modfied dataframe based on the original index.

Comment: @PrintableBao See update where I rewrote in pure lambda function without the extra function call.

Comment: great that looks better and easier. can you talk about the reset_index and also (level = 0, drop  = True) arguments?

Comment: When you do a groupby it puts a another index level on the resulting dataframe.  But to assign the results back to the original dataframe the indexes much match.  So, you need to drop that index created by the groupby.  That is why I do a reset_index(level=0, drop=True).  It removes that newly created index level by the groupby.

Comment: Great that makes sense. And the level = 0 does that as well?

Comment: The level=0 tells it which index to drop.  The index start with zero for the outside going in.